# Key down up and home not working in JS

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, struts2

I am calling javascript for Key down and keyUp event in Struts2 textfield, so for both key down and up event I am handling events like checking the decimal point and validity etc.
Textfield looks like this:

```xml
<s:textfield downkeydown="javascript:down(this,event);" 
                 onkeyup="javascript:upevent(this,event);"
               maxlength="14" />
```

Upevnts and down event are handling values entered something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17583713/5086633

But because of this arrow keys (up, down, right, left) are not working.

Should I handle these keys separately, if yes how??

Comment: Can you add your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly specify all the keys in the javaScript to allow these keys using an OR operator...keycodes in my case that were blocked were as follows-->

End 35
Home
 36
Left Arrow
 37
Up Arrow
 38
Right Arrow
 39
Down Arrow
 40

So, I allowed these keys in my script.
But please take care of all browsers..event.keyCode,event.charCode should be used depending upon browser types (handle Browser compatibility issues)

Can use this chart..http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html.. It proved useful to me.