# Javascript validation won't allow periods/decimal points

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm having some trouble adding validation for stops to my input box. The restriction on allowing numbers only (second condition) works, but the first condition may as well not exist. Full stops and decimal points still do not appear in the input box.

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
   if (charCode == 110 || charCode == 190)
      return true;
   else if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
      return false;

   return true;
}
```

Additionally, I've noticed that the behaviour of this JS is different across browsers. in FireFox, I can use the numeric keypad to enter a value. However, in Chrome I am limited to the top row of numbers. Neither browser allows decimal points.

Comment: you're using OnKeyPress, up or down?

Comment: @saranshkataria OnKeyPress

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow only numbers or decimal point in form field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583685/allow-only-numbers-or-decimal-point-in-form-field)

Comment: @saranshkataria Oh. Why on earth is there so much variation in key codes?

Comment: Try `<input type="text" pattern="\d+(\.\d+)?" />`

Comment: @Tushar No good. I'm looking to disallow the entry altogether, not allow it and fail. Besides, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onkeypress` won't report the key codes, it will report the ASCII character typed. You want `onkeydown`

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
   
   if (charCode == 110 || charCode == 190)
      return true;
   else if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
      return false;

   return true;
}

document.getElementById('foo').onkeydown = isNumberKey;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="foo" />
```

Comment: Conditions can be combined in a single, `if (charCode !== 110 && charCode !== 190 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;`

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer didn't work either. I'm still limited to numbers only.

Comment: Hmm.  It's working when running the snippet right here. Can you edit your updated code into the question, so we can see what else is up?

Comment: Your new example returns `false` for 110, 190, 46. Don't you want `true` there?

Comment: Gah. I tried that on a whim earlier, completely forgot to change it back.

Comment: @PaulRoub Is the numeric keypad not working to be considered expected behaviour with JS?

Comment: No clue. Might be a good separate question, which someone other than me will answer :-)